# I get a Suspicious pointer conversion in function main. How to get rid of this?

Tags: turbo-c

I'm new here at stackoverflow. The title is my question. Can someone please help me on this. Thanks. I've been working on this for like 3 days.

This part of code encodes the file to a huffman code

```
void encode(const char *s, char *out)
{
    while (*s) {
        strcpy(out, code[*s]);
        out += strlen(code[*s++]);
    }
}
```

This part of code deciphers the file from a huffman code to a human readable code

```
void decode(const char *s, node t)
{
    node n = t;
    while (*s) {
        if (*s++ == '0') n = n->left;
        else n = n->right;

        if (n->c) putchar(n->c), n = t;
    }

    putchar('\n');
    if (t != n) printf("garbage input\n");
}
```

This part is where I get my error.

```
int main(void)
{
    int i;
    const char *str = "this is an example for huffman encoding", buf[1024];

    init(str);
    for (i=0;i<128;i++)
        if (code[i]) printf("'%c': %s\n", i, code[i]);

    encode(str, buf); /* I get the error here */
    printf("encoded: %s\n", buf);

    printf("decoded: ");
    decode(buf, q[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare 'buf' in a different line, and not as 'const':

char buf[1024];

Answer (score 1):

The `const` applies to all the declarations on the line, so you're declaring `buf` as a `const char[1024]`. That means that calling `encode` casts away the constness, resulting in the warning.

Avoid having multiple variable declarations on the same line, unless they are all *exactly* the same type.